# How to run a function in two threads using python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

So I have a function that takes a long time, and I want to speed it up. I did all I could to optimize it, but it still takes a very long time. I want to multiprocessing to speed it up, using 3 or 4 threads. Everything I found online either gave me a way to run 2 functions at the same time (this particular function you cannot split up into different parts and combine them at the end), or a way to run the same function with different inputs, which also doesn't help me.

Thank you!

Comment: Divide and rule.

Comment: if this function cannot be split up into different parts and recombined, it's probably not a good candidate for multithreading

Comment: Maybe you don't understand this, but you can't just "add threads" to make a function work faster.  It's *possible* that you could split the function up so that two or more processes could run simultaneously and complete the work in less wall-clock time.

Comment: Use PySpark. Or just the threading library. Chop up the data into batches and send each down a thread that writes the output to something that can handle multiple IO